# How to get authentication from user in linkedin?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am new in creating a application in linkedin. Can some one help in getting the authorization??

I tried this code:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
                                           &client_id=78lv1rv8ryh1hf
                                           &scope=scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network
                                           &state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424
                                           &redirect_uri=http://www.mycoolsite.com
```

I am getting error saying that ...

```
error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=We+only+support+a+response_type+of+"code"%2C+but+you+passed+code+
```

Comment: Is that all ? traceback ...!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be improved:

1. you have not URL-encoded the `redirect_uri` parameter value
2. you're passing `scope=` in the scope *value*, which seems to be a typo/duplicate
3. you may have inserted a space/line-break in your URL since the following works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=78lv1rv8ryh1hf&scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef424&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycoolsite.com